# PHP cURL POST bad output

Tags: php, curl

I am getting some info from a https web server using PHP plus cURL. All info got as HTTP GET is ok but when I need to do some HTTP POST I get a no sense output. Web server is ok as If i get the info from a web browser all works ok.

I am using following code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1"); 

if($method == "POST"){
    print_r($post_fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);     
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array (
        "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Language: es-es,es;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3",
        "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
        "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"
    ));
}

if ($usecookie) { 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $usecookie); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $usecookie);    
} 

if ($refer != "") { 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $refer ); 
} 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
```

Answer header is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 20 Nov 2011 11:04:39 GMT
Server: Apache
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
max-age: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.4 JSP/2.0
idWl: PRO-LOW16_6604
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Any idea about where the problem could be?

Comment: Could you give us the whole HTTP headers section? I mean, including the status header.

Comment: By nonsense output, you don't mean gzipped output do you?  Can you explain what *exactly* your problem is?  To be blunt: we're not magic and can't help you debug your code from afar without ample information.  Also, have you tried to emulate a web browser request exactly?  If the server is fine, then it's something in your request code that the server doesn't like.

Comment: Sorry for not to being more explicit. Request output is not a readable text as expected. I can only see symbols.

Comment: You say in your headers that you accept gzip, so the server responds with gzip'ed data. I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It clearly shows its gziped...

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Passing the returned data through the below function will inflate it back to readable content.

```
function gzdecoder($d){
    $f=ord(substr($d,3,1));
    $h=10;$e=0;
    if($f&4){
        $e=unpack('v',substr($d,10,2));
        $e=$e[1];$h+=2+$e;
    }
    if($f&8){
        $h=strpos($d,chr(0),$h)+1;
    }
    if($f&16){
        $h=strpos($d,chr(0),$h)+1;
    }
    if($f&2){
        $h+=2;
    }
    $u = gzinflate(substr($d,$h));
    if($u===FALSE){
        $u=$d;
    }
    return $u;
}
```

Comment: Adding curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip"); to request works ok

Comment: Good, Im glad you got it sorted.